# Parse .txt to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, parsing

I have a txt file, which has the following structure

```
Title: Blazing Saddles
Release Year: 1974
Format: VHS
Stars: Mel Brooks, Clevon Little, Harvey Korman, Gene Wilder, Slim Pickens, Madeline Kahn

Title: Casablanca
Release Year: 1942
Format: DVD
Stars: Humphrey Bogart, Ingrid Bergman, Claude Rains, Peter Lorre

Title: Charade
Release Year: 1953
Format: DVD
Stars: Audrey Hepburn, Cary Grant, Walter Matthau, James Coburn, George Kennedy

Title: Cool Hand Luke
Release Year: 1967
Format: VHS
Stars: Paul Newman, George Kennedy, Strother Martin
```

I already have file data in string format.
Somehow I must convert it to JSON
I've to try split in this way

```
file.buffer.toString().split('\n')
```

But how should I move on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split on the newline character, split each of those strings by the colon symbol. Use `reduce` and create a new object in the accumulator `a` when there is a blank line, otherwise set properties in the most recent object in the accumulator for every non-empty [key,value] pair encountered.

```js
const s = `Title: Blazing Saddles
Release Year: 1974
Format: VHS
Stars: Mel Brooks, Clevon Little, Harvey Korman, Gene Wilder, Slim Pickens, Madeline Kahn

Title: Casablanca
Release Year: 1942
Format: DVD
Stars: Humphrey Bogart, Ingrid Bergman, Claude Rains, Peter Lorre

Title: Charade
Release Year: 1953
Format: DVD
Stars: Audrey Hepburn, Cary Grant, Walter Matthau, James Coburn, George Kennedy

Title: Cool Hand Luke
Release Year: 1967
Format: VHS
Stars: Paul Newman, George Kennedy, Strother Martin`

console.log(s.split('\n').map(i=>i.split(': ')).reduce((a,[k,v]) =>
  (!v && a.push({}) || (a[a.length-1][k]=v), a), [{}]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this npm library.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/export-from-json
Also we can get  other formats  csv, txt, xls etc.
You can check my usage example:  https://github.com/devStack03/node-csv-json-export